# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is very basic but I'm new to JS and new to React, I need a few pointers on what I'm doing wrong. I have a `Slider` components I would like to change, and I would like to reflect/store the new value of the `Slider` in the class state. How should I be writing this?

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

Code example below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value1: 1
      };
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Slider</Text>
                    <Slider 
                    value={this.state.value1}
                    onValueChange={(e) => this.setState({value1: e.target.value})}
                    minimumValue={1}
                    maximumValue={5}
                    step={1}/>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }
  
export default App;
```

Comment: there isn't `mood` property in your state, you have just set `value1` property in your state.

Comment: just edited to reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no mood property in your code, I highly recommend you to work with functional components instead of class components to be able to use hooks and make your code more clean and readable.
for more information check [React Functional Components VS Class Components](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/react-functional-components-vs-class-components-86a2d2821a22)

I revised your code, now it updates the state of value1 whenever the slider moves:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';



    const App = (props) =>{
      const [value1 , setValue1] = React.useState(1)


        return(
            <View>
                <Text>The value is : {value1}</Text>
                    <Slider 
                    value={value1}
                    onValueChange={setValue1}
                    minimumValue={1}
                    maximumValue={5}
                    step={1}/>
          </View>
      );
    
  }
  
export default App;
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@shahem/demo)

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example where I can write `setValue1` to a readable state?

Comment: what do you mean by readable state?

Comment: Sorry, just not sure how I can use the value of the slider, for example writing the value of the slider after it's been changed to an API or local storage

Comment: you can use the new value simply like this : {value1}  and if you check this line you see how I am using it to print the new value to the screen.
                <Text>The value is : {value1}</Text>

Comment: to assign it to a local storage :
localStorage.setItem("itemName", {value1} ); 
To use it :
 localStorage.getItem("itemName");

Comment: please mark the question as solved if there's nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

No mood property in your code. So it is undefined.